# GMail RSVPAction to Google Calendar

Tags: html-email, google-apps, schema.org, google-schemas

I've had success in using [this google apps script](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/) to test RSVP actions, the action button appears in the inbox, but my end goal is to get it to post an event to the recipient's Google Calendar on a "Yes" or "Maybe". It currently does not display the response options, nor post to the calendar.

I'm using the example code from https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/rsvp-action

The schema also requires an HttpActionHandler to direct the request (to google calendar in this case). Is there a way to direct this to the users Google Calendar using a generic URL? Any url based invitation I've found seems to require the user to set options in Google Calendar and getting its "Magic Cookie" from there.

(I realize that Google says GMail RSVP actions are 'unsupported' but it seems to work so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the RSVP Action to direct the request from your email to Google Calendar. The RSVP Action is meant to be used with a third party application that can handle the requests, such as Evite or similar apps.

Comment: Ah thanks, I had a feeling. So do you have any idea if this is possible at all through any of the actions? I know I can leave the text unstyled and it will give the date a link, but my client is very picky about styling.

Comment: The best way to interact with Google Calendar is with the Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). You may consider using the API in your backend and have a Gmail Action talk to that, but you'll still need users to authorize your app to update their calendars.